# Python Django refusing to create user and telling me to download Pillow (again)

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm trying to create a new superuser within my admin files, and I receive this error.

```
PS C:\Users\sefni\Desktop\AtlasStore> py manage.py createsuperuser
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
store.Product.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
        HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip install Pillow".
```

Thing is I have already installed pillow before making making migrations to my data, it worked successfully since I have my 0001_initial.py.

This is the error given when I try to install pillow again.

```
PS C:\Users\sefni\Desktop\AtlasStore> pip install pillow
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1


+ pip install pillow
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Content of my admin files:

```
    from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Category, Product

@admin.register(Category)

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'slug']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'author', 'slug', 'price',
                    'in_stock', 'created', 'updated']
    list_filter = ['in_stock', 'is_active']
    list_editable = ['price', 'in_stock']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
```

[image]

VENV folder:

[image]

Comment: Hey, this looks like an Python environment problem. Apparently your system can not even find the pip command. Are you are using a virtual environment? If so you need to activate it first.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken Hi, I've updated my post. I have VENV not sure what more i need to do

Comment: Yes. VENV is you virtual environment, but it seams not to be activated. e.g. `PS C:\Users\sefni\Desktop\AtlasStore>` there should be a `(venv)` in front of it. Try this command `venv/Scripts/Activate.ps1`  to activate is (assuming the name of your virtual environment is `venv`)

Comment: Alternatively you can select the venv in VS Code by clicking on the Python tag in the status bar and select your venv as environment.,

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

had to go into venv\Scripts\activate and run then choose 'always run' from the options :)